# Python socket data evaluated using if statement behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning about sockets in Python and I wrote a short server socket program on one machine which can be polled using `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 8888`. The communication works fine but for some reason when I am evaluating the `data` which is sent from the client, it does not seem to evaluate as it should.

The offending code is below:

```
    data = conn.recv(1024)    # receive data
    conn.sendall(data)        # reply to confirm what data was received
    if data == "green":
            reply = 'GREEN ON'
    elif data == "red":
            reply = 'RED ON'
    else:
            reply = 'Command not recognized'
    conn.sendall(reply)
```

From the client I do the following:

```
telnet 192.168.0.8 8888
Trying 192.168.0.8...
Connected to 192.168.0.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter       # server responds with connection confirmation
green           #typed from client
green           #server responds with the data it received
Command not recognized        #<-- data is not evaluated correctly in if statement
```

So what is happening is I poll the server using `telnet`, which responds with `Welcome to the server...` indicating a successful connection. Then I type in `green`, the server responds with the data it received (i.e. `green` hence the same line twice) but then tells me the command is not recognized, implying the `if` statements on the server program did not evaluate `data` correctly.

Am I missing something, like the data is actually null-terminated like `green\0` leading to incorrect evaluation in the `if` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're presumably typing something and hitting Enter, just as the instructions say.

So, you're sending `'green\n'`. Or maybe `'green\r\n'`.

And either way, `'green\n' != 'green'` and `'green\r\n' != 'green'`.

A good way to test for this is to print out what you get. Printing the [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of a string will quote it and escape all control characters, so you'll see exactly `'green\r\n'` instead of just `green` followed by a blank line, which is a lot easier to interpret. (This would also let you rule out spurious `\0` terminators, etc.)

You could fix this by checking, e.g., `data.rstrip()` instead of `data`.

However, once you do that, your program will not actually *work*, it'll just work *most of the time*, or *in certain situations* (like testing on localhost). This is a recipe for hard-to-catch bugs that will require you to rewrite your whole app when you finally find them.

A `recv` might get the data from a single `send`, or half the data from that `send`, or the data from three separate `send`s. And if you receive `'gre'` or `'green\r\nbl'`, no amount of manipulation is going to make that match `'green'`.

To deal with this, you need to design a protocol that delimits messages in some way, and loop over `recv`, adding to a buffer, and splitting off messages. Or, if your protocol is just "terminate every command with a newline" (and there are no embedded newlines within commands), you can just use [`socket.makefile`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile), which gives you a file-like object that automatically does that for you—so you can just iterate over it line by line (or call `readline` on it, etc.), just like you can with a regular file. You can even open it with universal newline support, so you don't have to worry about pesky inconsistent `\r\n` vs. `\n`.

See [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed that line of code to read `if data == "green\n"` but still the same.

Comment: @exantas: Put in a `print(repr(data))` statement to see what you're actually receiving. I'll be it's a `\r\n` vs. `\n` problem, but really, there's no reason to keep guessing.

Comment: You were right, it is indeed receiving `green\r\n`. That's a good tip though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is likely that a newline is being sent from telnet. Try stripping trailing whitespace before the `if` block:

```
data = data.rstrip()
```